# How to get a Eclipse like hints in the MS Blend 4

Tags: xaml, expression-blend

How to get hints in MS Blend 4? In Eclipse this is CTRL+Space, here it does not work.

When I write something wrong the hint list disappears and I have to remove chars to the `=` sign so they will appear again.

[image]